# vagrant-aws plugin installation error

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I am trying to install the aws plugin for vagrant but getting an error.  I am running vagrant 1.9 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1.  I have no ruby expertise so I can use all the help you can provide.
I tried installing ruby version 2.3.3, but based on the paths below vagrant is using the embedded version.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'fog-xml' (>= 0) among 45 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:319:in `block in activate_solution'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:316:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:316:in `activate_solution'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:244:in `internal_install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:97:in `install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:62:in `block in install_plugin'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `install_plugin'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in `block in execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:66:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/bin/vagrant:123:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Vagrant 1.9.1, as I also had this same issue with the vagrant-rackspace plugin, but it installs fine now.

Comment: I confirm.  Upgrading to vagrant 1.9.1 solved my issue. thanks!

Comment: On OSX, that's `brew cask reinstall vagrant`. There is no "upgrade" for casks.

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same issue on current Arch Linux.  I'll also add that even if I:

```
vagrant plugin install fog-xml
Installing the 'fog-xml' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'fog-xml (0.1.2)'!
```

Or:

```
`gem install fog-xml`
```

I get the same error condition.

Comment: Are you using Vagrant 1.9?  do you know if you got this error with a prior version?

Comment: It does seem to be a problem unique to vagrant 1.9, and I believe it's fixed with this:


https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8079/commits/3dccd82a39bfb9929070b043a9144fa20191220d